# how can I control a metal temperature at 140-160 degrees?

Tags: power-supply

I need to keep a metal plate temperature at 140-160 degrees, what kind of sensor should I use?

Comment: Please confirm that the temperature you want is 140-160 Celsius (not Fahrenheit). In the US, some non-technical people use Fahrenheit, and I can't tell if you are in the US or elsewhere.

Comment: With that tremendous range, you might just get away with a bimetallic thermal switch. However, a thermocouple and PID control will almost certainly meet your requirements, whether degC or degF.

Comment: I confirm this is celsius. in fact I need it to be 150 celsius with a 5% tolerance.

Comment: i better add that my plate is about  1 cubic meter and it is important to be in the range for the whole area. thank you

Comment: PID temperature control with thermocouple or RTD depending on your budget

Comment: Whether you have a plate of 1 sq m area, or a box of 1 cubic m volume, your #1 issue will be control of uniformity of temperature across it. It will either need to be hewn from solid aluminium, or have circulating oil, unless it is well insulated all round with low heat losses.

Comment: It is going to have serious edge effects unless it is a sphere (which you say it isn't.) With that tight tolerance across the entire surface, you'll need multi zone controls, I think. Of course, a lot depends also on the environment surrounding it. Asking about a sensor is probably putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: K type thermocouple. Platinum RTD. Some thermistors. Control is going to be themajor issue. A proper description of the problem rather rthan hints MAY get you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a plate, it should be 1 square meter, not one cubic meter... unless it isn't a plate?

If you want very good temperature uniformity on your surface, then it'll be hard. It'll also depend if you place cool stuff on it, if air blows on it, or if anything produces local cooling.

You could use a hollow plate and circulate a liquid through it.

You could also consider a phase change system: hollow chamber filled with boiling liquid. This works like a plat heat pipe. Newer GPUs use "vapor chamber cooling" which is the same principle.

So, you use a heating element to boil a liquid. Vapors will condense on the coldest spot and heat it. This gives you quick temperature uniformization.

Now, you get to choose the liquid and operating pressure.

It is much safer if said liquid boils above 150°C at atmospheric pressure, because this allows you to operate the chamber below atmospheric pressure. Leaks or other problems result in the thing sucking in air, rather than spitting burning liquid. Also, pressure vessels are a problem.

Now... I suggest finding a heat pipe/vapor chamber manufacturer and talking to them.

Comment: A plate indeed has volume, and it is perfectly relevant for computing the thermal load.

Answer (score 0):

In free air you would generate quite a wind. That wil blow off your dreams of uniform temperature. Your possiblities to keep it together:

- numerous local sensors, heaters and subcontrollers in addition to the master controller
- sink your plate into high boiling temperature fluid, warm the fluid
- have an owen and keep its door closed
- apply all the abowe combined.

These are not in contradiction with the question. Even should your plate be a straight plane, adding other walls was not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Since no details are given, then you could use a pressure sensor: pressurise a container containing the plate to 500 kPa (5 bar) and circulate boiling water.

At that pressure water boils at 150°C, therefore by monitoring the pressure you can monitor the plate temperature, as long as you keep the water boiling (and condensating on the outer surfaces of the box you will use).